# Can't get any data for cloud functions from database

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

It always times out and does not print anything

[image]

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.https.onRequest(async (change, context) => {
  // If un-follow we exit the function.

  // Get the list of device notification tokens.
  const fcm = admin.firestore().collection('fcm');
  const snapshot = await fcm.get();
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.get('uid'));
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The function always times out because it never sends a response to the client.  For HTTP type functions, you are required to send a response after all the async work is complete in order to terminate the function correctly, as stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

Your function has another problem in that the names of the parameters are different than normal.  You have `change, context`, but that only applies to database functions.  Since you have an HTTP function, the parameters are normally called `req, res`, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

Minimally, you could simply call `res.end()`.

```
exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const fcm = admin.firestore().collection('fcm');
  const snapshot = await fcm.get();
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.get('uid'));
  })
  res.end();
})
```

Comment: ty for the improvements but this does not solve my problem :x
I don't want any reply to my client, I just want to get all data from a database, edit data in another database and send out notifications. But I'm still stuck at the first object of getting the data in the first place... console.log doesnt print out anything... just : i  functions: Beginning execution of "sendFollowerNotification"
i  functions: Finished "sendFollowerNotification" in ~1s

Comment: As I said, you are obliged to send some response to the client in order to terminate the function correctly.  There are no alternatives for HTTP type functions.  If you want to send notifications as well, you're going to have to write that code.

Comment: I know :D I terminated it correctly after your reply... and I also know, that I need to implement what I want to do... obviously... but I still wonder why I can't get log for the data I should get from the forEach function